# How to take screenshot if Assert.AreEqual fails? How to put if condition with Assert.AreEqual?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to take screenshot of failed test case in C# selenium.

But i dont know how to use if condition with `Assert.AreEqual`.

I tried using `if(Assert.Equals == false)` also but that's not working.

Can anybody help??

Answer (score 1):

Well actually, "Asset.AreEqual" accepts three parameter 
1. expected result in bool
2. Original result in bool
3. error message

if expected and original does not match it will throw an error and for the screenshot u need to use try-catch, I have used this long ago.

public void AreEqual(bool expected, bool result, string comment = "",string pictureName = "")
        {
            try
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(expected, result, comment);

```
        }
        catch
        {
            /// will capture a screenshot of errors
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment))
            {
                int length = comment.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length;
                if (length > 30)
                    length = 30;
                pictureName = comment.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Substring(0, length);
            }
            pictureName = (pictureName == "" ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : pictureName);
            GetScreenShot(pictureName);

     // Getscreenshot function capture image for me u need to put your code here(before throw)     
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd help to see more of your actual test, but since `Assert.Equals` doesn't return a value, you could break it down into multiple steps.

For example, if you have this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(value1, value2);
```

Then you could replace it with this:

```
var areValuesEqual = (value1 == value2);

Assert.IsTrue(areValuesEqual);

if (!areValuesEqual)
{
    // rest of testing logic
}
```